# the error message while running model_test.py for tensorflow deeplab

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been trying to test the installation of [deeplab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) by following this

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/
python deeplab/model_test.py
```

However, I got the following error message, in specific,

```
    2018-04-25 10:54:23.488868: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at mkl_concat_op.cc:784 : Aborted: Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not create a concat primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_concat_op.cc:781           
    E...                                                                                                                                              
    ======================================================================                                                                            
    ERROR: testForwardpassDeepLabv3plus (__main__.DeeplabModelTest)                                                                                   
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------      

The complete traceback is as follows

2018-04-25 10:54:23.488868: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at mkl_concat_op.cc:784 : Aborted: Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not create a concat primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_concat_op.cc:781           
E...                                                                                                                                              
======================================================================                                                                            
ERROR: testForwardpassDeepLabv3plus (__main__.DeeplabModelTest)                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call         
    return fn(*args)                                                                                                                              
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1312, in _run_fn          
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)                                                                                    
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1420, in _call_tf_sessionrun                                                                                                                                                
    status, run_metadata)                                                                                                                         
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__   
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))                                                                                                         
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AbortedError: Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not create a concat primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_concat_op.cc:781                                                                                      
         [[Node: concat = _MklConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _kernel="MklOp", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ResizeBilinear, aspp0/Relu, concat/axis, DMT/_283, aspp0/Relu:1, DMT/_284)]]                                                                        

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deeplab/model_test.py", line 108, in testForwardpassDeepLabv3plus
    outputs_to_scales_to_logits = sess.run(outputs_to_scales_to_logits)  
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)                                                                                                              
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1140, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)                                                                                         
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    run_metadata)                                                                                                                       
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)                                                                                                 
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AbortedError: Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not create a concat primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_concat_op.cc:781                                                                                      
         [[Node: concat = _MklConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _kernel="MklOp", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ResizeBilinear, aspp0/Relu, concat/axis, DMT/_283, aspp0/Relu:1, DMT/_284)]]                                                                        

Caused by op 'concat', defined at:
  File "deeplab/model_test.py", line 120, in <module>
    tf.test.main()                                   
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/test.py", line 76, in main
    return _googletest.main(argv)                                                                                                 
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/googletest.py", line 99, in main
    benchmark.benchmarks_main(true_main=main_wrapper)                                                                                   
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/benchmark.py", line 338, in benchmarks_main                                                                                                                                                 
    true_main()                                                                                                                                   
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/googletest.py", line 98, in main_wrapper  
    return app.run(main=g_main, argv=args)                                                                                                        
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run                 
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/googletest.py", line 69, in g_main
    return unittest_main(argv=argv)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 256, in runTests
    self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/unittest/runner.py", line 176, in run
    test(result)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 653, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "deeplab/model_test.py", line 105, in testForwardpassDeepLabv3plus
    image_pyramid=[1.0])
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/models/research/deeplab/model.py", line 296, in multi_scale_logits
    fine_tune_batch_norm=fine_tune_batch_norm)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/models/research/deeplab/model.py", line 461, in _get_logits
    fine_tune_batch_norm=fine_tune_batch_norm)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/models/research/deeplab/model.py", line 424, in _extract_features
    concat_logits = tf.concat(branch_logits, 3)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1181, in concat
    return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 949, in concat_v2
    "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3290, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/dsp_emerging/ugwz/virtualE/deeplab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1654, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

AbortedError (see above for traceback): Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not create a concat primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_concat_op.cc:781
         [[Node: concat = _MklConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _kernel="MklOp", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ResizeBilinear, aspp0/Relu, concat/axis, DMT/_283, aspp0/Relu:1, DMT/_284)]]


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 23.571s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roll back to Tensorflow 1.6

This issue is still being addressed in versions 1.7 and above.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17494

Comment: Hi Srinivas, I rolled back to tensorflow 1.6, and get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Colab, in Runtime type Python2 or Python3, with GPU, I run without any error using commands:

```
!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
%env PYTHONPATH=/env/python/:/content/models/research/:/content/models/research/slim

!python /content/models/research/deeplab/model_test.py
```